# How do I enable XDMCP login in Ubuntu 14.04 from the initial Login screen?

Tags: login, xdmcp

I need to enable XDMCP from the initial GUI login screen.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and am connecting to a CentOS 7.0 XDMCP server.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding it to init.d   See this tutorial (http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDM_XDMCP.html)

Comment: This let me log into Ubuntu from another machine.  I want to use Ubuntu to log into another machine.